# javascript: copying one select list to another

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("one");
var len = x.options.length;
var y = document.getElementById("two");
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = option.value = x.options[i].value;
    y.add(option);
    x.remove(i);
}
```

However, I see the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

The elements in the first listbox too doesn't get removed. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing elements from `x.options`, but when you do that the list gets smaller and you are still iterating until the old value of length. So at some point you will get to an index that is past the end of your (now shortened) list and `x.options[i]` will be `undefined`. You can get around this by just iterating as long as `x.options[0]` exists, always removing the first element from the list:

```
var x = document.getElementById("one");
var y = document.getElementById("two");
while ( x.options[0] ) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = option.value = x.options[0].value;
    y.add(option);
    x.remove(0);
}
```

Or by iterating in reverse:

```
var x = document.getElementById("one");
var len = x.options.length;
var y = document.getElementById("two");
for (i = len; i--;) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = option.value = x.options[i].value;
    y.add(option,0);
    x.remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to remove elements from an array while you're iterating through it, as you can throw off your index. If you go through your elements in decreasing order of index instead of increasing, you should avoid this problem

Comment: for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  x.remove(i);
 } After the copy too failed to remove the items.

Comment: @sridhar You're still removing elements while iterating there. Going in decreasing order of index, as charlietfl suggests, could work